# How can I improve the following code's performance?

Tags: c, performance

Here is the Question.
Find the largest GCD of the input variable with the values of an array.

Inputs are as follows:-
First-line contains two integers, N and Q.

Second-line contains N integers which form the arr[].

Next, Q lines contain an integer M, the time in seconds she wishes to go back.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,q;
    scanf("%d %d", &n,&q);
    int a[n];
    int gcdn[n];
    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);      }
    while (q>0){
        q--;
        int x;
        scanf("%d",&x);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            gcdn[i] = gcd(a[i],x);
        }
        printf("%d \n",max(gcdn,n));
    }

}

int gcd (int a, int b) {
    if (b==0)
        return a;
    else 
        return gcd(b, a%b);
}
int max(int *a,int n) {
    int max= a[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<n;i++) {
        if(a[i]>min) {
            max= a[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

How can I make this code better in terms of competitive programming? And what other languages can make this code better and more efficient?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can keep track of the max value while calculating gcds, no need to store them and traverse again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most obvious performance improvement is that your array is not sorted: instead of simply adding an element to the array, you'll need to do a search first (which is `O(\log(n))`), but once you need to get the maximum of an array, you just need the first (or the last) entry.

Comment: This is hardly an improvement. You are suggesting to do an insertion sort, which is O(n log n) versus the existing O(n) solution. The most obvious way is stated in the comments section already.